# Hash function for OpenCV SURF descriptors

Tags: c++, opencv, hash, feature-descriptor

I am using OpenCV to extract image feature descriptors and store them for future query search. The problem is that searching a large database iteratively by euclidean distance is really costly and takes a lot of time. I need a hash function to create unique hash key for every descriptor. I am following [this](http://www.multimedia-computing.de/mediawiki/images/d/da/Bundle_Min-Hashing_for_Logo_Recognition_-_ICMR2013.pdf) paper.

**Can you please point me to a hash function that can generate hash keys for feature descriptors?**

**Edit:** What is the best method of storing feature descriptors in a database?

Comment: otherwise keep in mind, that hashing the descriptor means you need a hash function whose hashes are the more similar, the closer the descriptors are. Maybe you can use "spatial hashing" for higher dimensions than 2 or 3: http://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/

Comment: @Micka Yes indeed I need a hash function exactly like that. Generating equal hash keys for exactly matching descriptors would be ideal but I don't think its plausible.

Comment: try this paper, it shows, compares and cites two optimization techniques: best-bin-first-kd-trees and locally sensitive hashing https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cohen/mypapers/auclairAMR07.pdf

Comment: Try FLANN-based-matcher. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=flannbasedmatcher#flannbasedmatcher
They have already implemented kd-tree, LSH, etc.

Comment: @old-ufo Yes I have seen OpenCV FLANN, the problem is that it does not give me control over the descriptor database, it just computes the nearest neighbors. I just want a two column table where descriptors are stored by index (hash keys) and I can access them in ~O(1) time. Pretty heavy demand, huh?! :)

Comment: Zindarod, did you find a way to do that ? I'm interested and i don't find...
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: @lilouch Unfortunately no. You can check the papers from this author: http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/r/Romberg:Stefan.